# Searching in 2 tables in one query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently learning mysql, so I am very new to this, tried to find a solution elsewhere but was unable too.

I've got 2 tables, import_staff and import_student.

- The import_staff table has 3 columns, id, stafffirstname, and stafflastname
- The import_student also has 3 columns, id, studentfirstname, and studentlastname

I've got a form the allows the user to search by name for either a staff user or a student user.

I can get my query to search through one table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM import_staff WHERE CONCAT(stafffirstname,space(1),stafflastname) LIKE '%$queryString%' LIMIT 10
```

BUT..I  want the query to search through in both tables..  Not sure how to even start.  Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

BTW-Using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) :

```
SELECT id, stafffirstname AS name1, stafflastname AS name2 FROM import_staff WHERE CONCAT(stafffirstname,space(1),stafflastname) LIKE '%$queryString%' LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
SELECT id, studentfirstname AS name1, studentlastname AS name2 FROM import_student WHERE CONCAT(studentfirstname,space(1),studentlastname) LIKE '%$queryString%' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it with join

```
SELECT *
FROM import_staff
INNER JOIN import_student
ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t1.stafffirstname, t1.stafflastname, t2.studentfirstname, t2.studentlastname,
FROM import_staff t1, import_student t2
WHERE CONCAT(t1.stafffirstname,space(1),t2.stafflastname) LIKE '%$queryString%' LIMIT 10
```

This might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
    select id, stafffirstname as firstname, stafflastname as lastname  from import_staff
    union
    select id, studentfirstname as firstname, studentlastname as lastname  from import_student) t
where concat_ws(' ',firstname,lastname) like '%term%'
```

In your table definition, instead of studentlastname and the like you should just use lastname. The table names, import_staff and import_student, already provide namespace.